# custom syntax highlight doesn't match in parentheses

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-java

In a custom *java* syntax file (${HOME}/.vim/syntax/java.vim) I wrote

```
syntax match CommonVar /ret/
highlight CommonVar cterm=bold
```

with the intention display the word `ret` in bold.
I tested it with this example from a .java file

```
long ret = 42;
long somearray[] = {ret};
int otherarray[ret];
exit(ret);
```

and discovered that word `ret` is bold only in the first two lines, but not in the last two.

Surprisingly when I tested likewise with a custom *C* syntax file and the lines in a .c file `ret` was bold in all four lines!

What causes this behaviour and how can I modify my syntax file such that `ret` will always be shown in bold?

Comment: If I had to *guess*, I would say it had something to do with `contains`. You could probably use `syntax keyword` though